# How are ability modifiers affected by leveling?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement, ability-scores

I'm a new player. I've been poring over the 5e player's handbook, and I don't see this explained anywhere in "Beyond 1st Level" or in the details for my class.

I understand when leveling up how hit dice work, how my class features and spells work. I also see that at level 5 my proficiency bonus goes up to +3, but what I *don't* see anywhere is how my modifiers improve (strength, dexterity, constitution, etc) as I level. I know that they must, but I don't know how to roll it.

Answer (score 19):

One of your class features is called "Ability Score Improvement".

> When you reach 4th level, and again at 8th, 12th, 16th,
>   and 19th level, you can increase one ability score of your
>   choice by 2, or you can increase two ability scores of your
>   choice by 1. As normal, you can’t increase an ability score
>   above 20 using this feature.

Note that the levels at which you get an Ability Score Improvement are different for Fighters and Rogues.

Answer (score 7):

### You increase your Ability Score Modifier by increasing your Primary or Base Ability Scores.

Here's how.

You never roll to increase your Ability Score Modifiers.  You only roll to determine your starting primary ability scores.  Every class has a Class Feature which shows up for every class starting at level 4 called Ability Score Improvement.  Through these Ability Score Improvements, you are able to increase 1 of your primary ability scores by 2, or 2 of your primary ability scores by 1 point each.  Your primary ability scores are Physical: Strength, Constitution, and Dexterity; and Mental: Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma.

Every class except the Fighter and Rogue gain these at 5 different intervals:  Levels 4, 8, 12, 16, and 19.  The Rogue gains an additional Ability Score Increase option at level 10 for 6 intervals total, and the Fighter gains two additional Ability Score Increases at levels 6 and 14 for 7 intervals total.

Since your question is about how to increase your **Modifiers** and not the primary ability scores; your modifier for each stat goes up for each even number above 10.  So a score of 10 is +0 , a score of 12 is +1 , up to a non magical cap of 20 which grants you a +5 Ability Score Modifier.

Answer (score 6):

Each class has a different ability score improvement schedule.  You'll find the rules for this under the class entry in the PHB.  I believe all classes receive their first ASI (ability score improvement) at level 4.  Some classes have more than others -- the fighter has more than any other class, for example.

At each ASI, you can increase one ability by two, two abilities by one each, or if your game is using the optional rules for feats, forgo your ASI and take a feat instead. Note that some feats grant a benefit in addition to increasing a specific ability score.